# compiling pdftex 2.2 seconds with 2012 vs 29 seconds with 2018 version

Tags: pdftex, performance

I'm not quite sure where to start looking to fix this. I have recently migrated from an old Ubuntu 14.04 box using `texlive/2012` to an 18.04 box running `texlive-2018`.

### old box

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.10; using libpng 1.5.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

### new box

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00
```

The tex file contains quite a number of images which is where the slowdown seems to occur (compiling files without images is quite fast)

I'm passing in a format file, but, basically both jobs are called like this:

`pdfetex --output-format=pdf -fmt=$fmt_path -no-shell-escape -output-directory=$out_dir filename.tex`

Does anyone have hints on where to start looking to track this down?

I also *zipped up the 2012 directory* from the old box, and moved it onto the new box, and ran that. *the job completed in 2.2 seconds* on the new box. So it's not the disk or machine, it's something to do with 2012 vs 2018.

What I can see, in the logs, is that the 2018 version is *just a lot slower* processing the images. At least, with verbose turned on I can see it's taking ~600ms per image or so.

Sorry for a pretty wooly question, but, any help would be most appreciated!

### Update - 20th August 2018

I have done some more investigation.

1. It's not png's which are the issue. I created a document containing *just* pngs (we have a few different `figure` types which are included) and they both rendered in a similar speed on both 2012 and 2018 versions.
2. I created a document containing mostly broken image links. This one was interesting as it took about 0.2 seconds to build the broken document using 2012, but *almost 8 seconds* to build the same broken document on 2018. This suggests there's something very inefficient going on regarding the searching of files.

Anyway, continuing to investigate.

### Kpath debugging

I don't think this is actually it, but, here's a difference in logging out the searching between 2012 and 2018 (for the same file)

#### 2012

```
(apppath/texinput/tex/EA910706.FIG)kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any../acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any) => a
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first../acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first) => t
kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any../acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any) => a
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first../acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first) => t
```

#### 2018

```
(apppath/texinput/tex/EA910706.FIG)kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any) => a
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first) => t
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(openin_any) => a
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(try_std_extension_first) => t
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search.formatpath/acc4-pdf.fmt) => (nil)
kdebug:hash_lookup(texmf_casefold_search) => 1
```

Comment: Interesting observation! I am currently preparing lectures slides and compilation is terribly slow. Without further investigation, I have blamed it to lualatex so far, which I am using for the first time in a larger project.

Comment: I have the impression it is the page ship-out to PDF that is slowing things down.

Comment: Which format do the images have?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer that may be a very useful pointer (and I'll have to look into it further in a couple of days).  We insert .pngs _and_ various of our own formats which get turned into graphics. I don't actually write the tex so I'm not sure how to explain that further. Things like organic compounds etc. Anyway, I tried replacing all these special types with images, and it was heaps faster. I've run out of time today to look into it further, so it may be a deadend, but, it may not. I'll update when I have more. Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean that the compilation is only longer if there are missing images or could you also reproduce a significant slow-down even if all pictures were found. `kpathsea` changed in TeX live 2018 that it now tries to search case insensitive, see https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#news Maybe that or the changes required to get that done have to do with the performance decrease.

Comment: I did see that about case insensitive, but I didn't know when it had changed. I couldn't imagine that would count for so much of the time!. That said, I'll see if I can compile it with case-insensitive turned off and see what happens.

Comment: @moewe that was it... I added `texmf_casefold_search = 0` to our `texmf.cnf` and it worked. Do you want to add that as an answer and then I'll mark it as correct? (I don't want to steal your bounty!).  I'm also happy to write up the answer, just whatever you'd prefer. Many thanks! I'm astounded it's that much slower.

Comment: I'd happy if you wrote down an answer with what you found out. I can't really comment on the technical details, so my answer would involve quite a bit of speculation.

Comment: just to point out a typo: `20th August 2019` should be 2018... (fwiw)

Comment: fixed @jfbu, getting ahead of myself there ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The culprit for us turned out to be the case (insensitive) searching that has become the default for `kpathsea` in 2018. Thanks to @moewe for the pointer.

The fix was to add to our `texmf.cnf` file:

`texmf_casefold_search = 0`

After that, all of our pdftex jobs compiled at the speeds we were used to.

Comment: Perhaps raise this on the TeX Live list? I suspect the performance hit is not something that was anticipated (certainly wouldn't have been my initial suspicion).

Comment: I'll do that @JosephWright ... I'm kinda surprised no one has mentioned this before!